# R:Define column where first record is a calculation from other column and following records are updated using previous records from the same column

Tags: r, group-by, calculated-columns, dplyr

I want to create the column 'result' such that

```
df <- policy income expense rate result
1      1      50     250     2     75  (250/2-50)
2      1      50     35      2     05  ((75+35)/2-50)
3      1      50     35      2    -30  ((5+35)/2-50)
4      2      70     600     3    130  (600/3-70)
5      2      70     50      3    -10  ((130+50)/3-70)
6      2      70     50      3   -56.6 ((-10+50)/3-70)
```

The data frame is grouped due to which I am unable to repeat the logic for first record for each group. Please tell me on how can I achieve this

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using `for` loops.

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(policy = c(1,1,1,2,2,2),
                 income = c(50,50,50,70,70,70),
                 expense = c(250,35,35,600,50,50),
                 rate = c(2,2,2,3,3,3))
```

First we split the data by `policy` for grouping:

```
dftemp <- split(df, df$policy)
```

Then we initialize a list for our results and fill the vectors within the list with `NA` to avoid growing them within the loop:

```
resulttemp <- vector("list", length(dftemp))
for(i in 1:length(resulttemp)){
  resulttemp[[i]] <- rep(NA, nrow(dftemp[[i]]))
}
```

Now we loop over the splitted data to get our results:

```
for(i in 1:length(dftemp)){
  for(j in 1:nrow(dftemp[[i]])){
    if(j == 1){
      resulttemp[[i]][j] <- dftemp[[i]]$expense[j]/dftemp[[i]]$rate[j]-dftemp[[i]]$income[j]
    }else{
      resulttemp[[i]][j] <- (resulttemp[[i]][j-1]+dftemp[[i]]$expense[j])/dftemp[[i]]$rate[j]-dftemp[[i]]$income[j]
    }
  }
}
```

Afterwards we `unlist` our results and add them to the original data:

```
df$result <- unlist(resulttemp)

df
  policy income expense rate    result
1      1     50     250    2  75.00000
2      1     50      35    2   5.00000
3      1     50      35    2 -30.00000
4      2     70     600    3 130.00000
5      2     70      50    3 -10.00000
6      2     70      50    3 -56.66667
```

Note that the original data has to be ordered by the group before splitting!

Comment: Thank you LAP for the same. I do want to ask if there is any alternative for the split function in the first statement as I have millions of records and it is creating a list of huge size in memory. Thanks

Comment: It may be possible to use `dplyr`'s `group_by()` function, but I'm not sure how to use reactive values to create the new vector without the `for` loop.